# I want to solve the Too many SOQL queries. How can I reduce the number of queries?

Tags: apex, soql, query, governorlimits

Multiple queries are being executed depending on the data type as follows.
I want to reduce the number of queries as much as possible. What should I do?

```
 //Get contract event
    for(ContractInfo__c ci : [SELECT Id,esignId__c,dataType__c,StatusKorean__c,businessNo__c,requestByDepartment__c,requestByProfile__c,requestedBy__c FROM ContractInfo__c 
                                  WHERE esignId__c IN :esignIdToContractMap.KeySet() AND dataType__c = 'CONTRACT' ORDER BY eventAtLocal__c  DESC LIMIT 1]){
            varT_contractStatus = ci.StatusKorean__c;
            varT_businessRegNum = ci.businessNo__c;
            varT_requestedDept = ci.requestByDepartment__c;
            varT_requestedProfile = ci.requestByProfile__c;
            varT_requestEmail = ci.requestedBy__c;
     }

    
    //Get owner sign event
    if(triggerDataType == 'OWNER_SIGN'){
        ownerSignInfo = [SELECT Id,esignId__c,dataType__c,StatusKorean__c FROM ContractInfo__c 
                         WHERE esignId__c IN :esignIdToContractMap.KeySet() AND dataType__c = 'OWNER_SIGN' ORDER BY eventAtLocal__c  DESC LIMIT 1];
    }   

    if(ownerSignInfo.size() > 0){
        for(ContractInfo__c ci : ownerSignInfo){
            varT_ownerSignStatus = ci.StatusKorean__c;
        }
    }

    //Get CDD event 
    if(triggerDataType == 'CDD'){
        cddInfo = [SELECT Id,esignId__c,dataType__c,StatusKorean__c FROM ContractInfo__c 
                   WHERE esignId__c IN :esignIdToContractMap.KeySet() AND dataType__c = 'CDD' ORDER BY eventAtLocal__c  DESC LIMIT 1];
    }
    
    if(cddInfo.size() > 0){
        for(ContractInfo__c ci : cddInfo){
            varT_cddStatus = ci.StatusKorean__c;
        }
    }
    
    
    //Get owner event
    if(triggerDataType == 'OWNER'){
        ownerInfo = [SELECT Id,esignId__c,dataType__c,StatusKorean__c,ownerId__c FROM ContractInfo__c 
                     WHERE esignId__c IN :esignIdToContractMap.KeySet() AND dataType__c = 'OWNER' ORDER BY eventAtLocal__c  DESC LIMIT 1];
    }
    
    if(ownerInfo.size() > 0){
        for(ContractInfo__c ci : ownerInfo){
            varT_ownerStatus = ci.StatusKorean__c;
            varT_contractOwnerId = ci.ownerId__c;
        }
    }
    
    //Get shop event
    if(triggerDataType == 'SHOP' ||triggerDataType == 'MENU' ){
        shopInfo = [SELECT Id,esignId__c,dataType__c,AdStatus__c,ShopStatus__c,totalApprovedShop__c,StatusKorean__c FROM ContractInfo__c 
                   WHERE esignId__c IN :esignIdToContractMap.KeySet() AND dataType__c = 'SHOP' ORDER BY eventAtLocal__c  DESC LIMIT 1];
    }
        
    if(shopInfo.size() > 0){
        for(ContractInfo__c ci : shopInfo){
            varT_shopStatus = ci.ShopStatus__c;
            if(ci.totalApprovedShop__c != null){
                varT_totalApprovedShops = ci.totalApprovedShop__c;
            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most of times trying to *fix* the method where the last SOQL happens is worthless. Every query in the whole transaction counts against that limit, so even if the exception is thrown here, you should check the debug log of the whole transaction.

Comment: See previous comment. In your code, as `triggerDataType` only has one value only one of the queries guarded by that will run (assuming this code isn't inside a loop).